# Adding multiple alternative WHERE clauses in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to filter car models from a database. So I want to show all car models that are selected from every car make.

```
SELECT * FROM `used_cars` 
WHERE (`make`='GMC' AND `model` IN('Acadia','Yukon') 
OR (`make`='Ford' AND `model` IN('Fusion','Taurus')
```

So in this case 'Acadia','Yukon' are selected for GMC, so I want to display all the rows that have those models, and I also want to show the Ford models selected 'Fusion','Taurus'.
I think there is some error with my SQL syntax, but can't seem to work it out. How should the SQL be written?

Comment: Maybe unbalanced brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing some closing brackets?

```
WHERE (`make`='GMC' AND `model` IN('Acadia','Yukon')) 
OR (`make`='Ford' AND `model` IN('Fusion','Taurus'))
```